# Shortcode output always showing at top of page

Tags: shortcode

my shortcode output won't appear where I put it, but rather at the top of the content (top of the post/page content).

And here is my code

```
function service_shortcode_index() {
global $content;
$output = include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/service.php' );
return $output;
}

add_shortcode('service_mid', 'service_shortcode_index');
```

there are some regular HTML lists with widget in "service.php"

The content displays correctly, just in the wrong position.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your problem is with the `$output = include ....` statement. `include()` returns true or false based whether it was successful - not the content of the file being included. Use output buffering to get the content.

```
function service_shortcode_index() {
    global $content;
    ob_start();
    include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/service.php' );
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('service_mid', 'service_shortcode_index');
```

Comment: the exception to this is if the included file returns its output, for example if service.php contained just `return 'something';`, `'something'` would get assigned to `$output` rather than true/false.

Comment: You can also directly write `return ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [PHP function `include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (roughly speaking)  echoes the content and then returns a boolean value.

If you switch the `include` for `file_get_contents` then your `$output` will be a string of the file content rather than the boolean value indicating the success of the inclusion.

Works for me with Wordpress5.2 & PHP7.